# how to fetch data from multiple tables in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
I have three tables
1. users
id
name
email
2. Listings
id
user_id
name
3 ListingImage
id
list_id
image
```

Here i want a data in one query. where all data fetched based on users table (id) .
 i want data something like that

```
enter code here
 Array
(
    [user] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] =>abc
            [email] => abc@gmail.com
            [listing]=>
                    Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [user_id] => 1
                        [name] => abc list
                        [listingimage] =>

                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [list_id] => 1
                                    [image] => abc.jpg
                                )
                                [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 2
                                    [list_id] => 1
                                    [image] => abc.jpg

                                )

                     )
                )
            )
```

i have used hasMany but it will not give me accurate result can anyone help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering relations are one to many and you've `Listing` model class and `ListingImage` model class for `Listings` table `ListingImage` table respectively.

In your `User` model

```
public function listings()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Listing::class);
}
```

In your `Listing` Model

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ListingImage::class, 'list_id', 'id')
}
```

And now

```
$user = User::with('listings.images')->findOrFail($id);
```

will give you your desired results.

You can find more details here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: work fine Mahfuzul Alam. Now i am facing one problem i want only one listing with multiple images. it returns me listing index start with 0

Comment: if you want only one listing then change `hasMany` to `hasOne` in `listings()` relation. Simple!

Comment: Thank you so much :) it means a lot :)